# How to add additional elements in an existing json file

Tags: json, xml, powershell

This is what I am doing:

```
$appParametersXml = [Xml] (Get-Content "$appParameterFilePath\$appParameterFile") 
    $parameterJsonFile = "$appParameterFilePath\$applicationName"+ "." + $jsonFileName

    # Transform the "Parameter" elements into a nested hashtable.
    # Convert any values that can be interpreted as [int] to [int] and strip out any comments in the xml file.
    $hash = [ordered] @{}
    $appParametersXml.Application.Parameters.ChildNodes | Where-Object {$_.NodeType -ne 'Comment'} | % {
    $hash[$_.Name] = @{ value = if ($num = $_.Value -as [int]) { $num } else { $_.Value }
       }
    } 

    # Wrap the hashtable in a top-level hashtable and convert to JSON.
    [ordered] @{
    '$schema' = 'https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#'
     contentVersion ='1.0.0.0'
     parameters = $hash
     } | ConvertTo-Json |Out-File $parameterJsonFile
     Write-Host "The JSON File is: " $parameterJsonFile
```

After I build the hash table with existing information from the XML file, I need to add additional parameter values like this Before converting to JSON

```
"parameters":  {
               "applicationName":  {
                        "value":  "somevalue"
                                           },
               "applicationTypeName":  {
                         "value":  "somevalue"
                                               },
                "applicationTypeVersion":  {
                          "value":  "somevalue"
                  },
```

Everything that I have tried so far has given me this as additional values. The regular XML values are being converted the correct way but the additional items that I am adding before converting are coming up like this!

```
"applicationName":  "somevalue"
```

How can i seperate that out on different lines?

Comment: So you don’t want help from others?

Comment: :). Not what I said at all! I was trying to tag someone but i failed at it. appreciate everyone's expertise

Comment: Well I'm not going to lie, his help is among the best one can get here. :)

Comment: Can you just edit the original xml (using xml tools) so it's in final shape and then convert? Or not convert at all and just continue to use xml tools on the modified xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, assuming your input xml file looks something like this ...

```xml
<application>
    <parameters>
        <applicationName>My Awesome App</applicationName>
        <!--my awesome comment-->
        <applicationTypeName>Mobile App</applicationTypeName>
        <applicationTypeVersion>299</applicationTypeVersion>
        <!--my other awesome comment-->
    </parameters>
</application>
```

Here is my revised PowerShell ... you can't use `if ($num = $_.Value -as [int])` casting as it won't work for 0, as it would be interpreted as false. I prefer to break the steps down and test and check each. Also I've used `InnerText` for the node value instead of `Value` as typically `Value` is [evaluated as `$null`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.value?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1) and I'm not sure what your xml looks like.

```bsh
$fileXml = "./config.xml"
$fileJson = "./config.json"

$xmlContent = [Xml](Get-Content $fileXml)

# Transform the "Parameter" elements into a nested hashtable.
# Set any string values which are integers as [int] and strip out any comments in the xml file.
$parameters = [ordered]@{}
$nodes = $xmlContent.application.parameters.ChildNodes.Where{ $_.NodeType -ne 'Comment' }

foreach ($node in $nodes) {
    $parameter = $node.Name
    $value = $node.InnerText
    if ($value -match "^\d+$") { $value = [int] $value }
    $parameters.Add($parameter, @{ value = $value })
}

# if you need to add additional attributes, it's as simple as:

$parameters.Add("newParameter1", @{ value = "newValue1" })
$parameters.Add("newParameter2", @{ value = "newValue2" })

# Wrap the hashtable in a top-level hashtable and convert to JSON.
[ordered]@{
    '$schema'      = 'https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#'
    contentVersion = '1.0.0.0'
    parameters     = $parameters
} | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File $fileJson
```

And here is the output saved to the json file:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "applicationName": {
      "value": "My Awesome App"
    },
    "applicationTypeName": {
      "value": "Mobile App"
    },
    "applicationTypeVersion": {
      "value": 299
    },
    "newParameter1": {
      "value": "newValue1"
    },
    "newParameter2": {
      "value": "newValue2"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is good to convert a regular XML file into JSON. What do I do if I need to add additional Parameter elements into the hash table BEFORE converting to JSON. So I want the regular XML file, plus add some more parameters (that are NOT in the original XML file) and then convert it all to JSON>

Comment: Sorry, I dont think i was clear in my question above. I've edited the question and added more information

Comment: @Amy - I've updated the answer to provide the steps as needed. In your original question you were asking specifically about nesting the value attribute. Would appreciate if you could mark me as the answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs into this, it was as simple as doing this after the hash table gets created with the existing XML file

```
$appParametersFileName = "$appParameterFilePath\$appParameterFile"
            
    $appParametersXml = [Xml] (Get-Content "$appParametersFileName") 
    $parameterJsonFile = "$appParameterFilePath\$applicationName"+ "." + $jsonFileName
    # Transform the "Parameter" elements into a nested hashtable.
    # Convert any values that can be interpreted as [int] to [int] and strip out any comments in the xml file.
    $hash = [ordered] @{}
    $appParametersXml.Application.Parameters.ChildNodes | Where-Object {$_.NodeType -ne 'Comment'} | % {
    $hash[$_.Name] = @{ value = if ($num = $_.Value -as [int]) { $num } else { $_.Value }
       }
    }
    $hash["newvalue1"]=@{ value="value1"}
    $hash["newvalue2"]=@{ value="value2"}
    
    # Wrap the hashtable in a top-level hashtable and convert to JSON.
    [ordered] @{
    '$schema' = 'https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#'
     contentVersion ='1.0.0.0'
     parameters = $hash
     } | ConvertTo-Json |Out-File $parameterJsonFile
     Write-Host "The JSON File is: " $parameterJsonFile
```